# Add 2 integers with bit manipulation

Tags: integer, bit-manipulation, integer-overflow

I'm trying to add two integers with out using + sign. I get the idea that the sum without carry can be computed as a^b, and the carry can be computed as (a&b)<<1. The 0x7FFFFFFF is maximum number for 32-bit integer, but what does the mask do? Why the carry and a has to mod with MASK in each iteration? And when the result is greater than MAX_INT, what does the ~((a & MAX_INT) ^ MAX_INT) do?

```
def get_sum(a,b):
    MAX_INT = 0x7FFFFFFF
    MASK = 0x100000000
    while b:
        carry = ((a&b) << 1 ) % MASK
        a = (a^b) % MASK
        b = carry

    if a <= MAX_INT:
        return a 
    else:
        return ~((a & MAX_INT) ^ MAX_INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider `a = 13`, in binary `1101`, and `b = 5`, in binary `101`.

Especially we look at what happens in the `While` block, step by step, operation by operation, but let's ignore the `% MASK` operation for now.

```
                     carry=    a=    b=
     a      b   a&b     <<1   a^b carry
   1101   101   101    1010  1000  1010
   1000  1010  1000   10000  0010 10000
   0010 10000     0       0 10010     0
  10010     0 -> exit loop
```

a is binary `10010` = decimal `18` and thus less than `MAX_INT`, so **18 is returned as the (correct) result**.

The purpose of the mask operation is to ensure, that no overflow into the MSB occurs, which is possible when the numbers get large.

Do you think you can figure out the `Else` part by the same means as shown above?